# Custom Object empty after creation

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

I have a custom object: `Vendor` that extends `NSObject`. I am initiating it like so:

```
NSDictionary *vendorObj = [vendors objectAtIndex:i];
Vendor *vendor = [[Vendor alloc] initWithVendorInfo:vendorObj];
NSLog(@"VendorObj: %@", vendorObj);
NSLog(@"Vendor: %@", vendor);
```

Here is what the class looks like:

```
@interface Vendor : NSObject

    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *description;

    - (id)initWithVendorInfo:(NSDictionary *)vendorDetails;

@end

@implementation Vendor

- (id)initWithVendorInfo:(NSDictionary *)vendorDetails
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        _name = [vendorDetails[@"company_name"] copy];
        _description = [vendorDetails[@"description"] copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

If I NSLog `vendorObj` all the details are there. Once I initiate the `Vendor` object and NSLog it, the log shows:

```
2013-11-21 22:22:44.769 [48202:a07] Vendor:
```

I cannot seem to figure out why my object is nothing, no memory address, not even a null. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your `description` property. The `NSObject` class defines a `description` method. This method is called when you use a `%@` format specifier with an object.

Your `description` property is overriding that method.

Rename your `description` property to something else.

Comment: Excellent! I should have seen that. Thank you so much